# Get explode data to show in checkbox with others data

Tags: php, checkbox

I have string data in database table('fruit_select') like this

```
$fruit = "apple,orange,banana";
```

and i need to get all fruits in database table('fruits') like this

`$all_fruits = array('apple','banana','kiwi','melon','orange','watermelon');`

to show in checkbox but if have fruit in table('fruit_select'), in checkbox need to checked. 
How can i get all data to show with some data in table('fruit_select') to checked?

this my view code to show all data

```
foreach ($all_fruits as $fruit){
   echo "<label><input type='checkbox' value='".$fruit."'/>".$fruit."</label>"; 
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `$fruit = "apple,orange,banana";` and your database? Is that a row's value? If so I would restructure your table. The actual goal here though is not quite clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$fruit = "apple,orange,banana";
$fruitArr = explode(",",$fruit); // convert selecte fruits to array
foreach ($all_fruits as $fruit){
   $checkedStatus = "";
   // check if $fruit in $selected fruit array - make it checked
   if(in_array($fruit,$fruitArr)) { $checkedStatus ="checked"; }
   echo "<label><input type='checkbox' ".$checkedStatus." value='".$fruit."'/>".$fruit."</label>"; 
}
```

Output:

```html
<body>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="apple" checked="">apple</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="banana" checked="">banana</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="kiwi">kiwi</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="melon">melon</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="orange" checked="">orange</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="watermelon">watermelon</label>
</body>


Output:
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much =)